# Counting length of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object, that will have variable number of other objects in it. In other words I have a container Object, that has other children object in it. Children do have their own properties.

I need to find a number of children objects in it, for that I found two ways of doing it. I am interested which one is the best practice way.

First way:

```
var numberOfChildren = Object.keys(parentObject).length;
```

Second way:

```
var tempP = parentObject
            var count = 0;
            for (var p in tempP) {
                if (tempP.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    count++;
                }
                alert(count)
            }
```

Third Way:

```
var sizeofChildren= _.size(parentObject);
```

I have added the third way as well
Ideas?

Comment: obviously the 1st one..less work,less lines!!!

Comment: @MESSIAH yeah sure. In a perfect world... However if OP needs to support browsers I would say no

Comment: @PeeHaa The `Object.keys` method can easily be polyfilled.

Comment: Well yes so is `forEach`. Not sure if that is what OP is asking about. I might be wrong though